# Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘IO’

Tags: haskell

This is my function

```
getDateFromUser :: IO (Either UserError Day)
getDateFromUser = do
  Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
  currentTime <- getCurrentTime
  date <- Prelude.getLine
  let retrievedDate = utctDay currentTime
      dayFromUser   = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d" date :: Maybe Day
   case dayFromUser of
     Nothing -> Nothing
     Just validDay -> do
       let differenceInDays = diffDays validDay retrievedDate
       if differenceInDays >= 0 && differenceInDays <= 16
          then return $ Right validDay
          else return $ Left InvalidDate
```

and this error message

Expected type: IO (Either UserError Day)
Actual type: Maybe (Either UserError Day)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You forgot a `return` on line 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is `Nothing -> Nothing`, where the first `Nothing` is a `Maybe Day` and the second is a `Maybe (Either UserError Day)`.

You want

```
Nothing -> return $ Left InvalidDate
```

(or some other `UserError`).